# Java Graphics вывод и обработка

Tags: java, graphics

Изучаю графические возможности Java а также ближе знакомлюсь с языком. Читаю сейчас Java 7 самоучитель, как его освою начну более подробней читать Хортсманна.

Вопрос, есть код из книги - http://pastebin.com/eMaZ0yRC , у меня не грузится картинка, другой пример который без диалога, тоже не грузит. Может проблема IDE? Попробуйте запустить или скажите ошибки.

Второй вопрос. После того как я загрузил картинку и вывел мне ее надо переместить в массив. Точнее даже 3 массива под Red Blue Green. После некоторых манипуляций, мне необходимо будет вывести данные массивы на экран как уже собранную картинку. Работал на C++ с форматом bmp имею представление что и как, но не имею представления как работать в Java, да и еще выводить на экран

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема, скорее всего, в `java.awt.FileDialog.getFile()`, который возвращает не полный путь к файлу, а содержимое строки имени файла в открываемом диалоге. Если картинка в рабочей папке программы, то должно бы работать.

Код ниже соберет полный путь из папки и файла в диалоге.

```
FileDialog d = new FileDialog(this,"Загрузить изображение...",FileDialog.LOAD);
d.setVisible(true);
if ( d.getFile() == null ) return;

m_dateiname = Paths.get( d.getDirectory(), d.getFile() ).toString();
```

По второй части вопроса могу только посоветовать начать с документации по [java.awt.image.BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).